# How many @EntityScan annotations can there be?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, spring-data

I have multiple "microservices" Spring Boot apps.  Each has it's own package structure to run independently just fine.  Each may have it's own @EntityScan as well depending on whether or not I can use the auto-configure from a base package trick.

When I try to combine them into a single Spring Boot application, do the separate @EntityScan annotations all get honored? I am not seeing this behavior right now. It appears to only honor one @EntityScan and then I get the dreaded *could not autowire a custom repository because the JPA entity for it does not exist*.

Spring Boot 1.2.3-RELEASE

Answer (score 3):

They may well all get evaluated but it looks like the bean post processor (see [`EntityScanRegistrar.class`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityScanRegistrar.java)) will just overwrite whatever the previous value of packagesToScan was on the `EntityManager` bean, which is not what you want.

You could probably quite easily write your own bean post processor that builds a combined list from all of the `@EntityScan` annotations.

You could also relatively simply configure the EntityManager bean manually, or even more simply, use the Spring `@Profile` features to selectively enable and disable your `@Configuration` classes that have the `@EntityScan` annotation when running combined services.

Comment: There's a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/2757), targeted at 1.2.4, that will combine the configuration from multiple `@EntityScan` annotations

Comment: As of 1.2.5, this is supported.

Comment: @AndreaRatto, do you have a link showing the inclusion of this feature? I'm having issues that make me think this functionality is not in the software.